# After pressing back and calling history.back(); History.pushstate isn't instantiated / not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, modal-dialog, history.js

So, I am using history.js to create some sort of popup modal which effects history states.
I am loading jquery and than history.js
everything seems to be working fine, until I press back in my browser, load a page, and than close the popup with my mouse, than History is not working and history.pushstate returns null.

this is my javascript code:

```
`var urlPath;`
```

`(function(window,undefined){
        History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() {
            var State = History.getState();
            if(State.data.action == "show_popup"){
                $('html, body').css({
                    'overflow': 'hidden'
                });
                $('.lightbox-dimmer').fadeIn();
                $('.lightbox-dimmer').focus();
                $('.lightbox-load').fadeIn();
                $("#lightbox").load(urlPath+' .halfpage, .sidepage', function() {
                    $('.lightbox-load').fadeOut();
                    $('.lightbox-warp').fadeIn();
                    $('.lightbox-dimmer').click(function(event){
                        if ((!$(event.target).closest('.post-info').length && !$(event.target).closest('.post-auth').length))  {
                            $('.lightbox-dimmer').unbind();
                            History.back();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }else{
                History
                $('html, body').css({
                    'overflow': 'auto'
                });
                $('.lightbox-dimmer, .lightbox-warp').fadeOut();
                $('.lightbox-dimmer').scrollTop(0);`
            }
        });

```
    $('.post-image').click(function(){
        urlPath = $(this).attr('href');
        if (History.pushState({ action: 'show_popup' } , 'POST TITLE', urlPath)) {
            alert('pizza')
        }
        var State = History.getState();
        return false;
    });
})(window);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.post-image img').lazyload({
    effect : "fadeIn"
});
var $container = $('.posts');
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.post',
        isOriginLeft: false
    });
});

$('.post-image').click(function(){
    var urlPath = $(this).attr('href');
    History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", urlPath); //,rand:Math.random()
    return false;
});

});

(function(window,undefined){

var History = window.History;
var State = History.getState();

History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
    var State = History.getState();
    alert(State.data.state);
    if(State.data.state == 1){
        $('html, body').css({
            'overflow': 'hidden'
        });
        $('.lightbox-dimmer').fadeIn();
        $('.lightbox-dimmer').focus();
        $('.lightbox-load').fadeIn();
        $("#lightbox").load(State.url+' .halfpage, .sidepage', function() {
            $('.lightbox-load').fadeOut();
            $('.lightbox-warp').fadeIn();
            $('.lightbox-dimmer').one('click', function(event){
                if ((!$(event.target).closest('.post-info').length && !$(event.target).closest('.post-auth').length))  {
                    History.pushState({state:2}, "State 2", '/');
                }
            });
        });
    }else{
        $('html, body').css({
            'overflow': 'auto'
        });
        $('.lightbox-dimmer, .lightbox-warp').fadeOut();
        $('.lightbox-dimmer').scrollTop(0);
    }
});

})(window);
```